# to_dict('records') causing unsupported type: <class 'str'> error

Tags: python, pandas

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gdfaf.png)

Getting a unsupported type error, just updated pandas and ensured it is runnning version 1.0.3. Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error message, as text in the post itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using `.to_dict` on a Series, which doesn't support the parameter you are passing. ([see `pandas.Series.to_dict` documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_dict.html))

I think you got confused with the `.to_dict` from DataFrame which can effectively get `records` as first parameter. ([see `pandas.DataFrame.to_dict` documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html))

You can just write `flatmodel = df[['flat_model']]` to make the `flatmodel` variable a DataFrame (instead of a Series) so that the `.to_dict` won't fail anymore.

Comment: You could also to `sr.to_frame()` to convert a series into a dataframe